# Is there an API to pull emails and calendars of everyone in the company in Google Apps for business?

Tags: calendar, gmail, google-api, google-apps

The company I work in has Google Apps for business account and I want to create this pet project (guided by HR) in which I need to fetch all the emails and calendars of everyone in this company to do some analysis. I am not bothered with the content of the email I just need the sender's and reciever's info. Is there an API for that?

(assume I will have admin access to the account).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail IMAP and Google Calendar both support OAuth 2.0 authentication with a service account allowing you to authenticate as your end users to get/set/modify their data:

[Gmail OAuth 2.0 Authentication](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/xoauth2_protocol)

[OAuth 2.0 Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

[Google Calendar v3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/)

[Google Drive Domain-wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation)  (process is identical for Calendar v3 API all the way up to the point of building the service)